# Listing Images and Text in Android list view

Tags: android

In my RSS News Reader app,I am currently listing RSS titles in a List view using the following method.I have stored RSS data in array using this method, http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=166      .I want to list RSS feed images along with its title.I fetched image URL from RSS feed.Can anyone help finding a solution?

```
ListView lv1;

    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist , array.PodcastTitle));
```

Comment: My problem is,I dont know how to fetch images using its URL and list them in a ListView :-(

Comment: Look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/379693),its perfect solution suits your requirement

Comment: thanks alot Paresh....I vl make a try :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this custom or dynamic [Listview example](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html)

also see this to how to load [image from URL](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot mac! and thanks to Stackoverflow...this is the place I belong to :-)

Answer (score 0):

use as example given at https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a custom ListView adapter by extending a BaseAdapter and secondly you want to get images in Bitmaps.

here : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html you have an optimized ListAdapter

and here: [Dynamically populate Android ImageView with outside resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585493/dynamically-populate-android-imageview-with-outside-resources) you have a clue of how you can download an image and put it into a Bitmap (after that you can put it on to your ImageView)

Comment: Thanks Cata...Let me try it :-)