# Rss parser android with text on image

Tags: android, parsing, rss

I was thinking of an app that would pars images and text from a rss and that the output will be like this:
http://gromdroid.99k.org/Screenshot_2012-08-11-15-00-07.png
but my question is how i could get the image from rss in a imageview with fill_parent as width and that there would be an textview on the imageview.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040030/listing-images-and-text-from-rss-feed-in-android-list-view)

> See this custom or dynamic [Listview example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040030/listing-images-and-text-from-rss-feed-in-android-list-view)
>
> also see this to how to load [image from URL](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html)
>
> [image]

This is the most comprehensive [RSS reader tutroial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/) I've found as well.

Comment: But this is not text on the image and it doesn't work with rss right?

Comment: Thats an easy fix, See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242951/android-text-over-image .

Comment: I linked above to a better RSS example at the end of my post.